# Using background images in jade

Tags: css, node.js, express

I'm using express + node.js + Jade. I wrote up a jade file but I can't get the background image to appear. I played around with the body class and it seems to work for the text color but it doesn't use the background image

```
  body {
  font-family: "Josefin Slab" !important;
  background-image: url("concursum-bg.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

I made sure that the image is in the same folder as this jade file.

When I do view page source the html is:

```
body {
font-family: "Josefin Slab" !important;
background-image: url("concursum-bg.jpg");
background-size: cover;
color: white;
text-align: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I'm running this on localhost if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image file must be served so that it is accessible to the browser. When it's in the folder with the jade file (I'm assuming this is a `views` directory), it's not served by Express and so the browser can't get to it. To fix this, make the server serve the image file:

- In the main Express app, use `express.static` to serve static files from a directory:
  `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));`
- Now, create the directory for the files to be served from:
  `mkdir public`
- Create an image directory there, for sanity:
  `mkdir public/images`
- Move the file there
  `mv {views,public/images}/concursum-bg.jpg`
- Update your stylesheet, changing `url("concursum-bg.jpg");` to `url("/images/concursum-bg.jpg");`.
- Restart your Express app.

http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Where would I Create the "public" directory? In the directory where views is?

Comment: It worked,  but I was wondering why Express can't serve it when its in the views directory?

Comment: @SocketPhys Express just doesn't do that by default, and there's really no reason for it to.